# Naive Bayes in Spark MLlib

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes

I have a small file 'naivebayestest.txt' with this structure

```
10 1:1
20 1:2
20 1:2
```

From this data I'm trying to classify the vector (1). If I understand Bayes correctly the label for (1) should be 10 (with probability 1!). The program in Spark MLlib:

```
String path = "/usr/local/spark/data/mllib/bayestest.txt";
JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> training = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(jsc.sc(), path).toJavaRDD();
final NaiveBayesModel model = NaiveBayes.train(training.rdd());
Vector v = Vectors.dense(1);
double prediccion = model.predict(v);
System.out.println("Vector: "+v+" prediction: "+prediccion);
```

shows `Vector: [1.0] prediction: 20.0`

I obtain the same result with a training set of 1050 elements, 350 (1/3) of the form `10 1:1` and the rest `20 1:2` (2/3), and I still get the same prediction 20.0 for vector 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

In the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/NaiveBayes.scala) of Spark Naive Bayes implementation, you could find the link of algorithms which are implemented:

> 1. [Multinomial NB](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/naive-bayes-text-classification-1.html) which can handle all kinds of discrete data.  For example, by converting documents into TF-IDF vectors, it can be
>      used for document classification.
> 2. [Bernoulli NB](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/the-bernoulli-model-1.html) by making every vector a 0-1 vector.
>
> The input feature values must be nonnegative.

In your case, Spark used Multinomial NB (which is default), so let's dig into the algorithm.

Naive Bayes is often used for document classification, let me explain your case as a document classification case:

1. Let's say the classes are `ten` and `twenty`
2. Let's say input token (only one in this case) is `Spark`

So for your first row data, it will be: `Spark`
For the second and third, they will be: `Spark Spark`

**As what I understood from the Multinomial NB link, the algorithm could be summarized in this equation:**
[image: Equation]

where:
P(Ci) : *conditional probability of test data belonging to class i*
nf : *number of terms in the vocabulary*
Sij : *sum of term frequency for class i and term j*
Si : *sum of term frequency for class i*
λ: *lambda, the smoothing value*
v : *input test vector*
ndci : *number of row data in class i*
nd : *total number of row data*
nc : *number of classes*

**What happened in your case**

In your row data, there is **only one token**(or only one input feature), which means **`nf` in the equation equals to `1`**
so: **`Sij = Si`**

That will make the multiplier of vector:
`ln(Sij+λ) - ln(Si+nf*λ) = ln(Si+λ)-ln(Si+λ) = 0`

As a consequence, the equation now is:
 [image: New Equation]

Which means **the result doesn't depend any more on input vector!**

Now is the class who has the most row data wins the classification.

And that's why your prediction result is 20 instead of 10.

**In the end**

To avoid this, try using Linear Regression, Decition tree, Random Forests, GBT, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`Naive Bayes` model will be trained for all 3 records. Your assumption

> If I understand Bayes correctly the label for (1) should be 10 (with probability 1!)

is wrong here
Correct probability will be

```
P(10|1) = P(1|10) * P(10)/P(1)
```

It is by definition, but due to additive smoothing this formula may change. I am not sure what formula will that be. But it seems out due to additive smoothing the probability P(20|1) comes out to be greater than P(10|1). Hence you are given the result so.

And it would make more sense with lots of training data.

Comment: You are right but p(1|10)*p(10)/p(1) = (1*1/3 )/ (1/3) = 1

Comment: I have tried with a bigger training set (1050 elements) with the same result. Anyway thanks for your help